# How to define a custom mock allocator?

Tags: c++, stdstring, allocator

I'm trying to define a custom `std::basic_string` specialization with a mock allocator to log all memory operations that `basic_string` performs.

```cpp
struct MockAllocator : std::allocator<char> {
    char* allocate(size_t n);
    void deallocate(char *p, size_t n);
};

using CustomString = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MockAllocator>;

CustomString str("Hello World........ (more symbols to avoid SSO)");
```

This simple code doesn't call methods of my allocator. I can even skip definitions, and linker doesn't produce any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why doesn't? Moreover, I have plenty of other cases of this string usage, and the linker doesn't complain on missed definitions.

Comment: gcc? I'm seeing the same thing. gcc's basic_string template seems to mostly ignore the allocator type, and insists on using its own default, internal allocator. I stepped through the constructor and ...weird. There must be a reason for the weirdness I'm seeing, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Yes, it is gcc... OMG...

Comment: Try stepping through the constructor with gdb, it's illuminating. gcc's basic string's constructor does, carefully, stash the allocator object inside it. It wraps it within another object, for some unclear reason, but it does store the allocator object as part of the string. But then when the rubber hits the road, and it's time to allocate internal storage, it falls back to the default allocator. This doesn't look like a bug, but it must be intentional. Why, beats me. But there must be a reason. I'm too lazy right now but I'd try using MS's compiler on godbolt,org, see what happens.

Comment: Is there anything like `boost::basic_string`?.. My compiler doesn't support `std::pmr::string` yet...

Comment: It seems the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) implements an allocator which does what you need.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Where do you see this? `allocate` is called [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc#L155) on the traits class which is specialized on the `CharT`-rebound allocator [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L91). The problem OP has is that `MockAllocator` is not a proper allocator and either won't rebind to itself or at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes C++11 (and later) allocator semantics, which older compilers (even if they did otherwise implement C++11) may not have implemented fully yet.

---

Your type doesn't satisfy the allocator requirements because it doesn't rebind properly and so there is no guarantee how the code will behave.

A minimal stateless allocator looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct MockAllocator {
    using value_type = T;

    MockAllocator() = default;
    template<typename U> MockAllocator(const MockAllocator<U>&) noexcept {}

    T* allocate(std::size_t) { /*...*/ };
    void deallocate(T*, std::size_t) { /*...*/ };
};

template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator==(const MockAllocator<T>&, const MockAllocator<U>&) noexcept { return true; };

template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator!=(const MockAllocator<T>&, const MockAllocator<U>&) noexcept { return false; };
```

and is passed as `MockAllocator<char>` to the `std::basic_string`.

The template parameter is a requirement. An allocator must always be rebindable to other object types, which works automatically for templates of this form. Otherwise a `rebind` member must be provided.

The `==` and `!=` operators are a requirement. They determine whether the two allocators can deallocate memory allocated by the other. They can just return `true` and `false` respectively for a simple stateless allocator like this. Since C++20 the `!=` overload is optional.

For more complex allocators, escpecially stateful ones, other members which are currently defaulted via `std::allocator_traits` may be required to make it work correctly.

It is not necessary to inherit from `std::allocator`. In fact, before C++20, inheriting from `std::allocator` will cause its `rebind` to be inherited as well, which will incorrectly rebind to `std::allocator</*...*/>` instead of your `MockAllocator`, which violates the allocator requirements. Since C++20 `std::allocator` doesn't have a `rebind`, so then your non-template `MockAllocator` will not be rebindable at all, again violating the requirements.

The last part is probably why you see the behavior you do. Libstc++ is rebinding the allocator for `char` internally, which should be completely fine for a proper allocator, but your allocator rebinds to `std::allocator<char>` instead of `MockAllocator`, so that it will effectively just use `std::allocator<char>`.

Comment: And if you do decide to inherit `std::allocator`, you have to homehow get its `rebind` out of the way (or implement your own), otherwise it'll be preferred over adjusting the template argument.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, either it has a rebind (before C++20) or it doesn't (since C++20) and in either case it will break the rebind requirements with a non-template `MockAllocator`. I clarified that in the answer.

Comment: Your advice works, but on top of that I had to reintroduce the `size_type`, `difference_type`, `reference`, `const_reference`, `pointer`, `const_pointer` types in the namespace of `MockAllocator`, plus I had to define the `rebind` structure. Accepting the answer, thanks.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov None of these should be necessary. Can you show an example on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/hvKh1czh9) where it doesn't work without these?

Comment: @user17732522 All versions of GCC 4.x requires `rebind`.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov GCC 4.x is very old. It did not yet implement the expected C++11 behavior correctly.

Comment: Ok, but that was the compiler I had to use.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov In that case you basically need a C++98 allocator, which the above is not. Before C++11 there was a lot more required boiler plate, see https://howardhinnant.github.io/allocator_boilerplate.html#old for a minimal skeleton.